# How to convert a file path to a blob object?

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a string which is a path to a file on my system (example: /var/www/html/country.png)

I need to upload this file to a server using javascript/angular6. But the problem is that the server accepts the file to be sent as a html input file object or a blob.

For example, this code successfully uploads the file

```
            var form = new FormData();
            form.append("filedata", $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
            form.append("overwrite", "true");

            var settings = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": "https://www.example.com/api/upload",
                "method": "POST",
                "headers": {
                    "authorization": "Basic XXXXXXX=="
                },
                "processData": false,
                "contentType": false,
                "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
                "data": form
            }

            $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

What is the way to do this.

Comment: With a FileInput?

Comment: I just updated my question and added a working code snippet

Comment: @Phantom007 I don't think anyone was confused about what you were asking.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts What is the work around? Is there anyway i can convert the filepath to a blob?

Comment: @Phantom007 _read the answer_. No.

Answer (score 6):

If that were possible, it would have been a huge security breach. Imagine any website being capable of accessing a file just by having a string (hint: `/etc/passwd` is in the same place on every Linux distro).

In short, not possible. The user must actively select the file in the upload dialog opened by a `<input type="file" />`, you have no control over this process.